# Describing a point in im $\Bbb P_A^n/I \rightarrow$ Spec $A$ as those $p$ for which $\emptyset \neq V(I) \subset$ Proj $\kappa(p)[x_0,...,x_n]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Z$ be a closed subset of $\Bbb P_A^n$ cut out by functions $f_i$. Consider the map  $\pi: \Bbb P_A^n \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} A$. I am trying to see why the points $p\in \pi (Z)$ are precisely those for which the $f_i$ have a common zero in $\operatorname{Proj} \kappa(p)[x_0,...,x_n]$.

I understand that $q\in Z \Rightarrow q\supset (f_1,f_2...)$ and that we have a local homomorphism

$$A_{\pi(q)} \rightarrow (A[x_0,...,x_n]_{q})_0$$

Indeed, $\pi(q)$ is characterized as the only point of $\operatorname {Spec} A$ for which the above map makes sense and is a local homomorphism (if $\mathfrak a$ is a specialization of $\pi (q)$ then the map $A_{\mathfrak a} \rightarrow (A[x_0,...,x_n]_{q})_0$ will not be local, and if $\mathfrak a \not \subset \pi(q)$ the above morphism will necessarily be the zero morphism (for we can take a $g\in \pi(q)\setminus \mathfrak a$ that is invertible in $A_{\mathfrak a}$ but not in $(A[x_0,...,x_n]_{q})_0$. Well, but to say that the above is a non-zero local morphism is the same as to say that we have an injection

$$\kappa(\pi(q)) \rightarrow (A[x_0,...,x_n]_{q})_0$$

I guess that I should glue these maps now in some way as to get the description that I wanted, but I guess that I am not thinking of this in the right way because it's getting unduly complicated. Could anyone help?